# RAM-Problem using FFmpeg-PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am facing a weird problem.
I am using FFmpeg-PHP to create thumbnails of some videos, those thumbs I paste into a larger preview Picture, using gdlib.
That far everything works fine.
I am doing all that in a Loop, so ffmpeg-php has to make 10 to 20 preview-pictures of different videos. The Problem now is, if my script did the first preview-picture, it doesn't free the used resources, so I am running out of memory after the 5th video.

The question now is: Why? I destroyed and unset all resource-Handler, and so on...

Here is the Script:

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$extension = "ffmpeg";
$extension_soname = $extension . "." . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX;
$extension_fullname = PHP_EXTENSION_DIR . "/" . $extension_soname;

// load extension
if(!extension_loaded($extension)) {
    dl($extension_soname) or die("Can't load extension $extension_fullname\n");
    echo "Load FFmpeg-php!\n";
}

class VidPreview
{
    private $pathToVid;
    private $video;
    private $preview;
    private $previewX;
    private $previewY;

    public function __construct($pathToVid, $previewX, $previewY)
    {
        $this->pathToVid = $pathToVid;
        $this->previewX = $previewX;
        $this->previewY = $previewY;
        $this->video = new ffmpeg_movie($this->pathToVid);

        //init gd for main picture
        $this->preview = imagecreate($this->previewX, $this->previewY);
        imagecolorallocate($this->preview, 250, 250, 200);
        imagestring($this->preview, 5, $this->previewX/2, 20, "Preview!", 5);
    }

    private function makeScreenshot($frame)
    {
        $ff_frame = $this->video->getFrame($frame);
        if(method_exists($ff_frame, 'toGDImage'))
        {
            $screenshot = $ff_frame->toGDImage();
        }
        else
        {
            $screenshot = false;
        }
        unset($ff_frame);
        return $screenshot;
    }

    public function makePreview($pathToSave, $amountOfShots)
    {
        //get video-frame-number
        $frameNumber = $this->video->getFrameCount();
        $frameValue = round(($frameNumber / $amountOfShots))-1;
        $frameValueStep = $frameValue;

        $dst_x = 20;
        $dst_y = 40;
        while($frameNumber >= $frameValue)
        {
            $screenshot = $this->makeScreenshot($frameValue);
            if($screenshot != false)
            {
                if($dst_x >= $this->previewX)
                {
                    $dst_y = $dst_y + 20 + 135;
                    $dst_x = 20;
                }
                //copy screen to preview
                imagecopyresized($this->preview, $screenshot , $dst_x, $dst_y , 0 , 0 , 240 , 135 , 720 , 406 );//TODO FIX VID VALUES
                imagedestroy($screenshot);
                unset($screenshot);
                //TODO FIX PREVIEW BUG
                $dst_x = $dst_x + 240 + 20;
                $frameValue = $frameValue + $frameValueStep;
                echo '$dst_x: '.$dst_x." ".'$dst_y: '.$dst_y.' '.'$frameNumber, $frameValue: '.$frameValue.','.$frameNumber."\n";
            }
            else
            {
                fwrite(STDOUT, "FFmpeg-php messed up! I will just skip this screenshot... \n");
                unset($screenshot);
                $frameValue = $frameValue + $frameValueStep;
            }
        }

        if(!imagejpeg($this->preview, $pathToSave, 100))
        {
            imagedestroy($this->preview);
            unset($this->preview);
            unset($this->video);
            return false;
        }
        imagedestroy($this->preview);
        unset($this->preview);
        unset($this->video);
        return true;
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        unset($this->pathToVid);
        unset($this->video);
        unset($this->preview);
        unset($this->previewX);
        unset($this->previewY);
    }
}


?>
```

hope somebody can help, it looks a little nasty, because I added some extra unset .

Here is the function call:

```
        if(!file_exists($pathToPic.'/'.$dirName.".jpg"))
    {
        fwrite(STDOUT, "Making pictures of: ".$file." \n");
    $preview = new VidPreview($pathToVid,1000, 700);
    $preview->makePreview($pathToPic.'/'.$dirName.".jpg", 16);
    unset($preview);
}
```

this snippet runs in a for-each-loop.

PS: I already posted that thread here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10211381 and here: forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=125566
I hope you aren't too mad at me, but it is pretty important :(

Comment: Not having much time to look into it right now, my initial guess is some references aren't being dereferenced so some unsets don't really clear up memory. You can confirm by using `memory_get_usage` before and after. If you're not using PHP 5.3, it's much better at garbage collecting memory - try it.

Comment: I tried and will send post the result

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the tip. I did it and thats the result:

```
[Start] Function: __construct (Before doing anything). Used Memory: 749240
[wmv3 @ 0xaf8e9d0] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
Function: __construct (After making stuff). Used Memory: 2191352
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191808
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191808
[wmv3 @ 0xaf8e9d0] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680464
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191808
$dst_x: 280 $dst_y: 40 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 12230,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 540 $dst_y: 40 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 18345,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 800 $dst_y: 40 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 24460,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 1060 $dst_y: 40 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 30575,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 280 $dst_y: 195 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 36690,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 800 $dst_y: 195 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 48920,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 1060 $dst_y: 195 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 55035,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 280 $dst_y: 350 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 61150,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 540 $dst_y: 350 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 67265,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 800 $dst_y: 350 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 73380,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 1060 $dst_y: 350 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 79495,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 280 $dst_y: 505 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 85610,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 540 $dst_y: 505 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 91725,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 800 $dst_y: 505 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 97840,97851
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2191856
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3680512
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2191856
$dst_x: 1060 $dst_y: 505 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 103955,97851
[END] Function: makePreview (After unsetting everything). Used Memory: 749728
[REAL-END] Function: __destruct (After unsetting really everything). Used Memory: 748936
```

It looks pretty much the same for the other Videos. It always goes back to: 748936. I used: memory_get_usage();
Here are the results for memory_get_usage(true):

```
[Start] Function: __construct (Before doing anything). Used Memory: 1835008
[wmv3 @ 0x19c08dc0] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
Function: __construct (After making stuff). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
[wmv3 @ 0x19c08dc0] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 280 $dst_y: 40 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 13082,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 540 $dst_y: 40 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 19623,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 800 $dst_y: 40 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 26164,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 1060 $dst_y: 40 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 32705,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 280 $dst_y: 195 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 39246,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 540 $dst_y: 195 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 45787,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 800 $dst_y: 195 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 52328,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 1060 $dst_y: 195 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 58869,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 280 $dst_y: 350 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 65410,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 540 $dst_y: 350 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 71951,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 800 $dst_y: 350 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 78492,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 1060 $dst_y: 350 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 85033,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 280 $dst_y: 505 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 91574,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 540 $dst_y: 505 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 98115,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 3932160
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
$dst_x: 800 $dst_y: 505 $frameNumber, $frameValue: 104656,104670
Function: makePreview (before calling makeScreenshot). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (start). Used Memory: 2359296
Function: makeScreenshot (end). Used Memory: 2359296
FFmpeg-php messed up! I will just skip this screenshot...
FFmpeg-php messed up! I will just skip this screenshot...
Function: makePreview (After unseting $screenshot of makeScreenshot (case of failure)). Used Memory: 2359296
[END] Function: makePreview (After unsetting everything). Used Memory: 1835008
[REAL-END] Function: __destruct (After unsetting really everything). Used Memory: 1835008
```

So I guess everything is fine here, because:

```
[Start] Function: __construct (Before doing anything). Used Memory: 749240
[REAL-END] Function: __destruct (After unsetting really everything). Used Memory: 748936
```

So it is pretty much the same Memory-Usage, after unsetting everything.

But "ps aux" tells me:

```
root     21637 37.0 **37.9** 303952 198744 pts/1   R+   11:48  20:27 php upload.php
```

It starts at 1.2 and increases after every picture. (37.9 is the memory usage in %)

What is going on?